# Adding keys / values into a empty object using a loop that iterates over 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

You are given an array of names along with an array of phone numbers. Using a loop, populate the existing phoneBook object to build a proper phonebook with the keys being people's names and the values being their respective phone numbers.

I don't know where to begin I am fairly new on how to add keys : values using a loop from an array into an object

```
const phoneBook = {


};
```

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++)

```
const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];

const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675']

console.log(phoneBook["Mira"]); //=> 3234958675

console.log(phoneBook["Royce"]); //=> 9164059384

console.log(phoneBook["Kathie"]); //=> 4154958675
```

I am getting undefined obviously as I haven't figured out how to get the loop to populate the object from the names and numbers arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over names and their indices (with a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop), and get the appropriate number from the numbers array (using the index):

```js
const phoneBook = {};

const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];

const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675']

names.forEach(
  (name, i) => phoneBook[name] = numbers[i]
);

console.log(phoneBook["Mira"]); //=> 3234958675
console.log(phoneBook["Royce"]); //=> 9164059384
console.log(phoneBook["Kathie"]); //=> 4154958675
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response I am going to try this out :) really appreciate this! I am still a n00b

Answer (score -1):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i ++){
  let name = []
  name.push(names[i])
  phoneBook[name] = numbers[i]
}
```